# Can we compress multiple .gz files to on gz file

Tags: bash

I can combine .sdf.gz many files to single file like this

```
cat CAAAML.xaa.sdf.gz CAAAMM.xaa.sdf.gz CAAAMN.xaa.sdf.gz CAAAMO.xaa.sdf.gz CAAAMP.xaa.sdf.gz > all.sdf.gz
```

I make a list in the directory

ls > list

```
CAAAML.xaa.sdf.gz
CAAAMM.xaa.sdf.gz
CAAAMN.xaa.sdf.gz
CAAAMO.xaa.sdf.gz
CAAAMP.xaa.sdf.gz
CAAARL.xaa.sdf.gz
CAAARM.xaa.sdf.gz
CAAARN.xaa.sdf.gz
CAAARO.xaa.sdf.gz
CAAARP.xaa.sdf.gz
CAABML.xaa.sdf.gz
CAABMM.xaa.sdf.gz
CAABMN.xaa.sdf.gz
CAABMO.xaa.sdf.gz
CAABMP.xaa.sdf.gz
CAABRL.xaa.sdf.gz
CAABRM.xaa.sdf.gz
CAABRN.xaa.sdf.gz
CAABRO.xaa.sdf.gz
CAABRP.xaa.sdf.gz
```

how can i combine the files using list into one sdf.gz

Thanks for the response.

Comment: Put them into an archive with `tar`.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

but if your question generally covers…

    a specific programming problem, or
    a software algorithm, or
    software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
    a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

…then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

gz is pretty common software tool and often used to automatize backups/etc.

Comment: As an aside, probably [don't use `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) even for this simple thing.